# Looping through value pairs in two columns of a data frame to look up osm data, extract element, and bind to new data frame in R with dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, openstreetmap

I am trying to write a custom function that does the following:

1. Takes a data frame as an argument. Data frame will have two columns: `city` and `state`.
2. Loops through the two columns of the data frame, passing the city and state in each row to `getbb` function of the `osmdata` package.
3. Extracts the elements `osm_points` and `osm_polygons` from the result of each successful `getbb` call and filters them to only rows that have non-blank `name` variable. (NOTE: Each of these elements is returned as a data frame. My attempt below tries to extract `osm_points` first with the idea I'd replace it with `osm_polygons` on a second function run.)
4. Row binds the data frames extracted in Step 3 into one large data frame.
5. Binds columns indicating city and state to the data frame in 4.
6. Row binds all data frames resulting from the loop covering Steps 2 - 5.

My attempt is below. I'm pretty sure I'm doing several things wrong here but can't manage to even correct the error I'm getting trying to complete the desired Step 3 above.

```
neighborhood_lookup <- 
  function(x,y) {
  getbb(x, display_name_contains = c(y,"United States")) %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = 'place', value = 'neighbourhood') %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  .$osm_points %>% 
  filter(!is.na(name))
  }

results <- 
  Reduce(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(loop_data)), function(i)
    neighborhood_lookup(loop_data$cities[i], loop_data$states[i])))
```

Resulting error is as follows:

```
Error in rbind.data.frame(...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grepl(display_name_contains, obj$display_name) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In grepl(display_name_contains, obj$display_name) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In grepl(display_name_contains, obj$display_name) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In grepl(display_name_contains, obj$display_name) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Are you expecting `getbb("[i]",` and `getbb("x"` to replace the value of the variable there? Because R doesn't do that. It passes them as literal strings to the `getbb` function. If you need to pass the value of a variable to a function, you pass the variable, like `getbb(x`.

Comment: @Spacedman, the getbb takes strings as arguments to the ```place_name``` (where I currently have ```"x"```) and ```display_name_contains``` (to which I need to pass the vector containing the state string that ```"y"``` stands in for) arguments. So you're saying I should eliminate the quotation marks around x and y in those spots? After doing so. I get a different error. I can denote it above in the body, if that indeed is your suggestion.

Comment: @Spacedman, just following up here: I think the function itself works (it runs fine when I pass arguments to it directly), but the remaining issue appears to be the ```Reduce``` and ```lapply``` portion iterating the function over two columns of a data frame.

Comment: Yes, `getbb("x",...)` looks for the bounding box of a place *literally* called "x". Is there a town called "x" anywhere? If you have variable named `x` you pass it to the function unquoted. EG: `x="London" ; getbb(x, ...)` (where my "..." is any other arguments you need) will search for London.

Comment: You should either delete the quoted string stuff or restart the Q from scratch with your latest results because the first part of it now irrelevant - the Q is a bit strung out now.